# Keeping an app running in the background

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, mobile-application

I have a mobile application that revolves around a timer that counts down on screen and sends various things such as text messages when the timer reaches a certain time along with changing color, vibrating etc etc. Is there a way to keep the app running in the background constantly so that it is not killed off? I am using a PhoneGap service so PhoneGap plugins are an option. I have tried one plugin called "Background Mode" here is the [link to the documentation](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode/tree/ac5fef831dbf9e567277dc900389923bd9bc7714). However this doesn't seem to work 100% of the time.

PhoneGap generates a config.xml, where I can change some of the properties/settings of the app. Here are the propeties/preferences (background related ones) I have defined in the config file.

```
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
<preference name="KeepRunning" value="true" />
<gap:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.background-mode" version="0.5.0" />
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: On iOS you will not be able to due this, first of all timers dom't work in the background. You can work around it by checking dates. Second only Location based, VOIP, Audio or app that communicate with some accessory are allowed to run in the background. Then Apple does not allow you to send an text message from code, you can only present the text message to the user which has to press send him self. This one you can love by send the text message via your own server.

Comment: @rckoenes Thanks for the heads up. I have noticed that it will be killed if it is not "communicating". I might try and implement some sort of location service that send data back to somewhere, but that is what that background mode plugin in meant to be doing. My text messages send fine on Android, so like you said I might have to send it via a server for the iOS version.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes finding the answer involves rephrasing the question.  Phonegap/Cordova in the mobile environment is very sensitive how background processes are used as these things can pull on the devices limited resources (battery & data limitations).

Change the way you are approaching this problem and you'll find that phonegap/cordova can give you the tools to accomplish your task.

In general it will be hard to keep an app running in the background for more than fifteen minutes using the phonegap/cordova framework.  Timers are almost out of the question.  Trust me I tried.  When the app loses focus it is suspended and may be shutdown completely if the device needs memory depending what platform you are using.

An alternative approach is to have your server handle the timing issues and send out push notifications that can wake up your app briefly and allow you to process and respond.  I've had success using a background fetch method which checks for updates and schedules notifications (some immediate, some to occur later).

Schedule notifications to occur as timed events that would prompt your user to open the app using the third party [local notification](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/1124) plugin.  Once the user hears and/or sees your notification and opens the app you can perform changes to the display as the app is resumed.  See http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/cordova_events_events.md.html for details on how to handle this event.

I hope this helps.. Good luck with your endevors

Answer (score 1):

Try using a service.I think this is what you really need.

**Activity may be killed but service will be preserved**

(as long as your hardware memory is not consumed by someone else, then service will be killed and restarted if you want)

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if I can actually make a service or not. I don't have a manifest or anything like that. Just a config.xml. I am using a program called "Alpha Anywhere", which a lot of people don't really know of, but it has a PhoneGap integrated service.

But you're right with the service thing.

Comment: for service, you may try this plugin ; https://github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-core Unfortunatly it's android only and it will require you extend the plugin with your own code